# Error finding a string in another string in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to return links that have the word "attach" in a list using Python on a web page. But every method I use to find that word in the link gives almost the same error.

This is my code and the error is received from line 16:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# pip install requests
import requests

def list_image_links(url):
    # Send a GET request to the URL
    response = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    image_links = []
    for image_links in soup.find_all('a'):
        href = image_links.get('href')
#if attach is in href
        word = 'attach'
        if word in href:
            image_links.append(href)
    
    print(image_links)
    return image_links

list_image_links('https://forum.ubuntu.ir/index.php?topic=211.0')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\...\main.py", line 22, in <module>
    list_image_links('https://forum.ubuntu.ir/index.php?topic=211.0')
  File "d:\...\main.py", line 16, in list_image_links
    if word in href:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Comment: Seems like `image_links.get('href')` returns `None` which is not iterable

Comment: Also next time please paste the entire backtrace.

Comment: Just a tip that's slightly unrelated to the question, but it looks like the variable you are returning out of the function and your step variable in your for-loop has the same name. This may result in you appending what you want to return to your step variable so it never gets returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my perspective, the error you're encountering is due to the fact that some of the `href` values returned by `link.get('href')` may be `None`, and you cannot iterate over a `None` value. To avoid this error, you can add a condition to check if `href` is not `None` before checking if the word is in it. Here's the modified code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def list_image_links(url):
    response = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    image_links = []
    for image_links in soup.find_all('a'):
        href = image_links.get('href')
        word = 'attach'
        
        if href and word in href:
            image_links.append(href)
    
# rest of the code...
```

The only change I made was adding an additional condition to the if clause, specifically `if href and word in href:`. I think this modification will resolve the issues.